# How to fix The Initial speed?

Tags: performance, path, simulation, anylogic

I have one problem with the speed simulation on Anylogic. I start to explain what I need:
I tried to recreate a real path of water taxi in Venice with different speed and acceleration (the code is below). To simulate it I used a statechart and I can't use any Library tool (Road,Pedestrian,Railway...).
My problem is: when I tried to running the simulation, I obtain wrong value of space because my agent is running with "initial speed" specified on the proprierties(as you can see in Figure below). I can't put this speed zero or with an empty space. What I "need" is a function that allows me to run the agent with my speeds in the code.

How I can fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvZ6b.png)

```
//ACCELERATION 0-7

if(v_sum<1.94)
           {index_tratta=0;
            a=main.Yellow.get(index_tratta).a;
            latitude=getLatitude();
            longitude=getLongitude(); 
                      
            v_part=a*t_iter;
            v_sum=v_part+v_sum;
            
            s_part=0.5*a*t_iter*t_iter;
            s_sum=s_part+s_sum;}
//COSTANT_7
else if(v_sum>=1.94)
           {index_tratta=1;
            v_sum=1.94;
            a=main.Yellow.get(index_tratta).a;
            latitude=getLatitude();
            longitude=getLongitude();
            
            s_part=v_sum*t_iter;
            s_sum=s_part+s_sum;}
//ACCELERATION 7-11
else if(latitude==45.445 && longitude==12.337)
           {index_tratta=2;
            a=main.Yellow.get(index_tratta).a;
            latitude=getLatitude();
            longitude=getLongitude();
                      
            v_part=a*t_iter;
            v_sum=v_part+v_sum;
           
            s_part=0.5*a*t_iter*t_iter;
            s_sum=s_part+s_sum;}
//COSTANT 11
else if(v_sum>=3.056)
            {index_tratta=3;
            v_sum=3.056;
            a=main.Yellow.get(index_tratta).a;
            latitude=getLatitude();
            longitude=getLongitude();  
                     
            s_part=v_sum*t_iter;
            s_sum=s_part+s_sum;}
//ACCELERATION 11-20
else if(latitude==45.460 && longitude==12.343)
           {index_tratta=4;
            a=main.Yellow.get(index_tratta).a;
            latitude=getLatitude();
            longitude=getLongitude();      
                
            v_part=a*t_iter;
            v_sum=v_part+v_sum;
            
            s_part=0.5*a*t_iter*t_iter;
            s_sum=s_sum+s_part;}
//COSTANT 20
else if(v_sum>=5.56)
           {index_tratta=5;
            v_sum=5.56;
            a=main.Yellow.get(index_tratta).a;
            latitude=getLatitude();
            longitude=getLongitude();
            
            s_part=v_sum*t_iter;
            s_sum=s_sum+s_part;}
//DECCELERATION 20-0
else if(latitude==45.490 && longitude==12.328)
           {index_tratta=6;
            a=main.Yellow.get(index_tratta).a;
            latitude=getLatitude();
            longitude=getLongitude();
            
            v_part=a*t_iter;
            v_sum=v_part+v_sum;
            
            s_part=0.5*a*t_iter*t_iter;
            s_sum=s_sum+s_part;} 
//ARRIVE
else if(latitude==45.50083 && longitude==12.33685)
    {isRunning=false;} 
}
```

Comment: Is this the same problem with your previous question?

Comment: Yes, Benjamin told me to delete the previous post and write it better

Comment: So, the long code that you have here doesn't function and the water taxis move only with the initial speed you have defined?

Comment: yeah, the program doesn't "see" these istructions and It moves the agent with initial speed

Comment: There can be many things happening here. Can you share your agent list, how and where you create water taxi agents, where does this assignment operation take place? Does each water taxi agent have speed as a variable? if you have multiple such taxis you need to assign speed one by one.. `waterTaxis(0).speed = blabla`

Comment: Firstly I can't post images yet.  The agent was created in Main and, by now, I have only one agent. In the following image, you can see the Water Taxi Agent; My code is written in "Tratta_Gis" into TrackLoopGis statechart. Please don't see the other statechart because now are work-in-progress, but they don't have any istruction of the speed profile.

Comment: sorry, but are you actually calling the code then? Please upload some images elsewhere and link to them here, really hard to follow without that (edit the original question)